# How to refresh current view in ViewPager

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I am using `ViewPager` with views V1, V2, V3 ..... I am trying to set visibility of a LinearLayout used in each view, by clicking on a button. Through this code it apply the change on the next view instead of the current view. e.g. I am on V5. When I click it hides/show the object on V6. If I am going backwards from V6 to V5, then it applies the change on V4.

Here is the code:

```
public class FragmentStatePagerSupport extends FragmentActivity {
    static final int NUM_ITEMS = 10;
    MyAdapter mAdapter;
    ViewPager mPager;
    static int mNum;

    private Button btn_zoom;
    static LinearLayout LL_Head;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_pager);

        mAdapter = new MyAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        mPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        mPager.setCurrentItem(5);

        btn_zoom = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_zoom);
    btn_zoom.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
                if (LL_Head.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                    LL_Head.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }else{
                    LL_Head.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            }
        });

.
.
.


    }

    public static class MyAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
        public MyAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return NUM_ITEMS;
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return ArrayListFragment.newInstance(position);
        }
    }

    public static class ArrayListFragment extends ListFragment {
        static ArrayListFragment newInstance(int num) {
            ArrayListFragment f = new ArrayListFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt("num", num);
            f.setArguments(args);
            return f;
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            mNum = getArguments() != null ? getArguments().getInt("num") : 1;
        }


        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.sura_vpager, container, false);

            TextView tv1=(TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txtHead); 
            tv1.setText("Fragment #" + mNum);

            LL_Head = (LinearLayout)v.findViewById(R.id.LL_Head);

            return v;
        }
```

Please advise
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

In order to make a fluent experience the ViewPager not only loads the view you are currently looking at, but also the adjacent views. That means, that if you are scrolling from position 0 to position 1, what actually happens is that position 2 is loaded, so it will be ready when you scroll on. This is why the change is applied to the "next" view, rather than the current one (if you scroll from view 2 to 1, then view 0 is created).

Since you are setting the static LinearLayout in OnCreate, then it's only the last view to be created that is changed - and this will only ever be the one you are looking at, if you have scrolled to the end of the pager. Instead you should keep track of which fragment the user is looking at (ViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener()) and cache the fragment in your adapter. You then know which fragment position you want, and when you ask for it, you will just return the one you previously created (don't create a new one, then it won't work :)).

Or, the tl;dr version:
LL_Head is almost always set to be the next fragment, not the current one. Don't set it statically. Cache it in your PagerAdapter and reget it when you need it.

Edit:
Alternatively you may want to have the fragments listen to an event of sorts, which tells them whether they should show or hide the layout in question. Otherwise it will only be the current fragment that is affected by this, rather than all fragments.

Answer (score 0):

The numbering in Java starts from 0. Thus when you want to set the 5th item, you have to call mPager.setCurrentItem(4);

Hope this helps!

Comment: You did not read the last part of my description above: "....If I am going backwards from V6 to V5, then it applies the change on V4"